# poster can see all comments , commenters see only his comments in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble understanding please help me
This code work correctly for poster, 
If commenters comment on a post it shows all user comments, 
But I want commenters to see his only comment. hides all comments

```
    <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <% next unless [comment.user, @post.user].include? current_user %>

     all comment here 

    <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you render all post comments, instead comment by comment

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% next unless [comment.user, @post.user].include? current_user %>

  <%= render comment %>

<%end%>
```

`<% next unless [comment.user, @post.user].include? current_user %>` will go to next comment if `current_user` is not commenter or post owner, and thus you will render all comments for post owner and if user is not post owner you will render only comments created by him.

This can also be defined as

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% if [comment.user, @post.user].include? current_user %>
    <%= render comment %>
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

End result is the same

Comment: i want  hide comment

Comment: but i am getting error undefined local variable or method `comment'